# How to remove IE toolbar and menu bar

Tags: internet-explorer-6

We have a asp.net web application which will be used in an intranet environment on IE 6. We want to change the default configuration of the browser so that it's always rendered without the Tool Bars, Menu Bars and Address Bar, just the browser window frame and the status bar should be present.

We were looking at the IEAK toolkit for IE6 but it doesn't seem to have the option of turning all this off though you can turn off certain menus and toolbar options.

Any ideas of how this can be done, is there a group policy setting or something that we can utilize here to get this done?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the showing of toolbars, address bar,... before the page is loaded, because it's built client side.

So to solve your problem, I think you should write the first page (Enter page for example) Then when use click on the `Enter` link you open another page using VBScript or Javascript to remove toolbars, address bar,...

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of opening the browser using JS to get this behaviour, but I was looking for something which makes it the default behaviour for all the sites and not just our web application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated [Kiosk Mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780#)?

Also, you're deploying IE6 at the wrong end of its lifecycle.

It also sounds like your requirement is for an app *you're developing*; mandating that the browser is configured this way for all sites might make the customers unhappy. If you want to know how to open a browser window without those things for your site, *from* your site, I'd suggest a repost to StackOverflow.

Comment: As I mentioned it's an intranet application to be used in a controlled environment where this behavior is required. I am aware of how this could be achieved in the application, the reason the question is posted here is to know if there's a domain level setting or something that can be used to achieve this.

Comment: OK, so, looked at Kiosk mode? I don't know of a way you can mandate it through Group Policy, but if you can control shortcut creation, it might be workable. That said - if you're able to achieve it in the application, perhaps just do it from the application?