# start IE with no menu/address bar through command line in Windows

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to start IE with a bare window (not kiosk mode, needs to have the close button) through a command line option?

We have some pages in an internal web-app that needs alot of screen realestate and we only need the HMTL rendering of the browser not the other stuff.

I found http://www.quero.at/launcher.php but the last update is 5 years old.

[How to remove IE toolbar and menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351417/how-to-remove-ie-toolbar-and-menu-bar) Similar question but no answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it with .net is by console application with reference to the COM object of IE.

**Instructions**:

Create new console application in VS and reference to the Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw) type library.

**Example in c#**:

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
ie.Navigate(url);
ie.ToolBar = 0;
ie.AddressBar = false;
ie.Visible = true;
```

see more details at msdn: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
ie.Navigate("C:\\sample.htm");
ie.AddressBar = false;
ie.MenuBar = false;
ie.ToolBar = false;
// ... etc ... customize your heart out
ie.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this command line or do i have to write a separate app for that?

Comment: Put the program in a file called, say, "OpenInIE.js" and then run it from the command line as `cscript OpenInIE.js`.

Answer (score 1):

create a small .net application with embed browser control in it, like a windows form with embedded Internet component  on it.

check this out form more information## Heading ##

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977534.aspx

Comment: Do you know if such an app already exists? I found one (see link in question) but it seems outdated.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, so if you're not interesting in programming, you probably should ask on superuser instead.

Comment: @Raymond Chen From the Faq: software tools commonly used by programmers. I use IE all the time because i write and test my web-apps for IE. So i would say my question is legitimate on Stackoverflow. Just like i can ask Eclipse questions here.

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE. People ask Visual Studio questions too. But your question is more about asking about command line options for a program, which is more of a superuser thing.

Comment: Here is a better tutorial on using the Web Browser control... it really is one of the best ways to do it... http://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

You could always just run an embedded instance of Internet Explorer in a window within your app. This way the container can be whatever size you specify in your own window and the embedded instance of IE can be any size you want with that, without any of the normal browser toolbars/menus.

If you mention what you are developing your app in, might be able to point you to some references.

Comment: Edited my question, the app in question is a web-app. What we want is as much screen estate as possible when users use the web-app. Unfortunately thousands of our PCs still run on old CRTs with 1024x800

Comment: If it is a web app, then you are basically limited to what can be accomplished with the window.open method in javascript, specifically the optional parameters. Refer to:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471221/So-You-Want-To-Open-A-Window-Huh.htm